# checkbox forced on new line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a checkbox but it seems to always go on the next line.

I somehow fixed it by design but it goes back on the new line always.

This is sample checkbox I am copying from the web

```css
input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em;
  width: 113px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit1" name="fruit-1" value="Apple">
<label for="fruit1">Apple</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit2" name="fruit-2" value="Banana" disabled>
<label for="fruit2">Banana</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit3" name="fruit-3" value="Cherry" checked disabled>
<label for="fruit3">Cherry</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit4" name="fruit-4" value="Strawberry">
<label for="fruit4">Strawberry</label>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It does not show the behaviour you are mentioning

Comment: Why not wrap the checkbox in the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use display block for label:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
    input[type=checkbox]+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.2em;
  width: 113px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
  color: #fff;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fruit1" name="fruit-1" value="Apple">
        <label for="fruit1">Apple</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fruit2" name="fruit-2" value="Banana" disabled>
        <label for="fruit2">Banana</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fruit3" name="fruit-3" value="Cherry" checked disabled>
        <label for="fruit3">Cherry</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fruit4" name="fruit-4" value="Strawberry">
        <label for="fruit4">Strawberry</label>
    </div>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-cdn-sduu2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Sir i would be more thankful if you could also help me with my previously posted question.

Comment: Which question are you referring to, please provide the link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754050/bootstrap-alert-from-server-side-asp-net-using-javascript <--this

Comment: Looks like you are using .net for rendering the DOM, unfortunately i am not expert in .net